# Can you share data across multiple templates?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I sometimes find myself declaring the same data to multiple templates. For example:

```
Template.auction_page.auctionDurations = function () {
  return [ 30, 60, 120 ];
};

Template.auction_editor.auctionDurations = function () {
  return [ 30, 60, 120 ];
};
```

I can make it better by using a global:

```
Template.auction_page.auctionDurations = function () {
  return global.auctionDurations;
};

Template.auction_editor.auctionDurations = function () {
  return global.auctionDurations;
};
```

But is there any way to get rid of the declarations altogether? In other words, is there any way to share some global data to multiple templates by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a good solution (with the help of a Helper!).

Your global:

```
global = _.extend({}, {
  regions: [ "Americas", "Europe", "Asia" ]
}
```

The helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("global", function(name) {
    return global[name];
});
```

Now all your templates can make use of it:

```
<select>
  {{#each global "regions"}}
  <option>{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of a helper function is a pretty good general purpose solution. For completeness, you can also do a simple assignment:

```
Template.auction_page.auctionDurations = Template.auction_editor.auctionDurations;
```

Comment: Ah yes, this can be a good shortcut too. I would think that this may or may not work depending on the loading order. But a look at some of my existing code suggests that loading order does not matter in this case. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Loading order would not natter for two reasons: 1) you are explicitly getting the values irrespective of rendering order, 2) in this case specifically, the values are static (though it has worked for me with dynamic collections too).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) for this:

```
  Template.auction_page.auctionDurations = function() {
    return Session.get("auctionDurations");
  }
  Template.auction_editor.auctionDurations = function() {
    return Session.get("auctionDurations");
  }
```

A nice bonus of using Session is that, since it's a reactive data source, setting it will cause all Templates that depend on it to be re-rendered. So your auction durations will update as soon as you call `Session.set("auctionDurations", [ 30, 60, 120 ]);`

Comment: Sry, but you misunderstood. I wanted to get rid of these assignment declarations altogether.